# Defining and calling a global variable in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a login screen which compares data via a Dlookup in order to authenticate users. I would like to create a global variable upon a correct login that any form on the database can call on and then open a form based on what that value is. So currently I have everything set up as such.
 LOGIN FORM :

```
Option Compare Database
Public gstrUsr As String
```

LOGIN FORM:

```
Public Sub Command4_Click()
'Sets the login time to now and then authenticates user credentials
 Dim usr As String
    Me.Time = Now
Dim lvl As String
Dim lck As Integer
Dim sql As String
Dim msgapp As Integer
Dim chkusr As Variant
    chkusr = Nz(DLookup("[Username]", "Login", "[Username]='" & Me.Username.Value & "'"), "")
    msgapp = 0
    usr = Nz(DLookup("[Password]", "Login", "[Username]='" & Me.Username.Value & "'"), "")
    lvl = Nz(DLookup("[Level]", "Login", "[Username]='" & Me.Username.Value & "'"), "")
    sql = "INSERT INTO Log ( [User], [Time] )SELECT [Forms]![Login]![Username] AS Expr1, [Forms]![Login]![Time] AS Expr2;"
''" & [Forms]![ItemList1]![SRCB] & "'"
'Runs above sql which adds a time record for the selected username also removes the "You are about to update X rows", will use this in the future on the accounting functions
        If chkusr = "" Then msgapp = 1
        If chkusr = "" Then MsgBox ("Invalid Credentials")
            DoCmd.SetWarnings False
            DoCmd.RunSQL (sql)
            DoCmd.SetWarnings True
'If password is = to the value that is returned in the "usr" variable declared at the top via Dlookup it will open a form based on what that users "level" is otherwise displays and invalid credentials message box
            Do While msgapp = 0
                If usr = Me.Password.Value Then
                    lck = 1
                    msgapp = 3
                Else
                    MsgBox ("Invalid Credentials")
                    msgapp = 3
                End If
Loop

Do While lck = 1
    If lvl = "2" Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "MainB"
        gstrUsr = DLookup("[Username]", "Login", "[Username]='" & Me.Username & "'")

        lck = 0

    Else
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Main"
        lck = 0
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

FORM THAT LOADS AFTER SUCCESSFUL LOGIN: (Main form with buttons to get to other forms, I included a text box so I could see if the information is being passed to the second form)

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
Me.Text75 = gstrUsr
End Sub
```

How do I get the global variable to pass to the second form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define your public variable in a code module instead of the module of the form.

This way it'll be available from any module (if it's `public`)

Comment: I made a module and made the new variable public but it still isn't showing up on the second form. hmm.. I'll have to break it down some more.

Comment: Okay had an extra declare on the secondary form with the same name so that took precedence. You answer works.

Comment: Yup had to wait 5 mins :)